# How can I replace some old serial numeric keypads?

Tags: usb, serial-port, serial, input-device

My Problem:

I have some older serial numeric keypads that are getting hard to replace. I tried a USB keypad but the distance of the cord wasn't long enough, so I tried using a USB to ethernet and ethernet to USB extension. It works, but has intermittent problems. Sometimes it requires a reboot to get the system to respond.

My Questions:

1. Where can I get a variety of industrial grade devices?
2. Are there other alternatives to a USB keypad?
3. Can anyone give other suggestions to a solution. E.g. I thought of adding an LCD touch screen in place of the Keypad...

Comment: Does using a separately powered USB-hub give you any better success with the USB solution?

Comment: Have you tried a USB extension cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is "the highest quality serial numeric keypad on the market"

http://www.genovation.com/623.htm

The keys are rated for 50 million cycles, and the company seems to be an industrial product manufacturer.

Believe it or not, Wal-Mart sells these for $50

http://www.walmart.com/ip/Genovation-623-Micropad-623-Numeric-Keypad/13214991

What's the distance that you need these to be from the PC they are connected to?

Comment: You can also consider http://www.x-keys.com/xkeys/xkrs232.php

They also sell USB extensions that use RJ-45: http://www.x-keys.com/accessories/xkextender.php